# installing invidia gpu driver on ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: nvidia, vmware, gpu

We have a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM on ESXI and there has been an NVIDIA Tesla M10-8q GPU assigned to it
no, we can not install the drivers and we tested lots of solutions if there is a way to do it we will be thankful to hear it.

here is some info about the VM

kernel version : Linux 5.4.0-124-generic x86_64

PCI device: NVIDIA GRID vGPU grid_m10-8q

result of ***lspci | grep -i nvidia*** : 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Tesla M10] (rev a2)

os-release of the ubuntu :

*NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

VERSION_ID="18.04"

HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"

SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"

VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic*

Comment: What have you tried and how did your attempts fail?

Comment: downloaded the GPU drivers and while installing it dkms errors like

ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 340.93 -k 5.4.0-124-generic`:
       Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

       Building module:
       cleaning build area...
       make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-124-generic module KERNEL_UNAME=5.4.0-124-generic; make -C uvm module
       KERNEL_UNAME=5.4.0-124-generic KBUILD_EXTMOD=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.93/build/uvm......(bad exit status: 2)
       ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 340.93 not found

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423633/edit) the question instead, so that you can apply proper formatting.

Comment: Do you really have to build and install it yourself? Does `ubuntu-drivers devices` not suggest a recommended driver package?

Comment: yes 
ubuntu-drivers did not suggest anything
and I have to do it manually
and now I am stuck

Comment: Add the Graphics Drivers PPA - https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa - then you'll be able to install v. 340 normally. Keep in mind 18.04 will be out of support in less than a years. Consider upgrading to a newer LTS or request ESM.

Comment: i get this new error


dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib' with
  different file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.108-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new nvidia-340 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.108-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)